# How to import functions from a given list of functions's name of a module?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, import-module

```
from importlib import import_module as a
X= ["pi", "pow", "sin", " cos", "tan"]
for items in X:
    a(f"math.{items}")
```

**This show me an error that no module named math.pi .**

**please help me**

I just want to ask how to import method or function using this way.

Comment: There is no module named `math.pi`. The module's name is `math`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `getattr` to access a modules object's, then assign it to global symbol table:

```
import importlib

importObjects = {
    'math': ["pi", "pow", "sin", "cos", "tan"], 
    'os': ['path']
}

for module, items in importObjects.items():
    module = importlib.import_module(module)
    for item in items:
        tmp = getattr(module, item)
        globals()[item] = tmp

print(pi)
print(path.exists)
```

Out:

```
3.141592653589793
<function exists at 0x10f1b6160>
```

Comment: Thanks sir a lot  : )

Comment: Sir you don't know your little help gives a large blow in my learning. Once again thanks because this small things didn't find easily.

Comment: You might want to up vote/accept the answer in case it solves your question, so it can be used to help others in the future.